# Can I install a 32-bit JVM and a 64-bit JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm using a JNI library that uses a 32-bit JVM. The current JVM installed on my machine is 64-bit. Is there any way I can have a 32-bit JVM and a 64-bit JVM installed? Or any wrapper that I can use?

Comment: Why would you do that in the first place?

Comment: 32 bit libraries run flawlessly on 64 Bit jvm, so I think another installation is not necessary.

Comment: You mean to install a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit machine?  Yes, that's possible.  But, we don't know which OS you're using.

Comment: Should just work. Is it a native library?

Comment: That isn't always true @Pradeep.  I have had situations where I'm dependent on 32-bit libraries via JNI and I needed to have both a 64-bit and 32-bit JVM available.

Comment: Is your question badly posed? Don't you mean on 64-bit OS?

Comment: Yes, It's a JNI library and it does not support 64-bit JVM.

Comment: Be an angel and edit your question; especially the title ;-)

Comment: @jgitter That's the exception since it isn't just a java library. Your solution should work in this case as he has clarified that it is a JNI library.

Comment: @jgitter, in most of the cases it should work, probably your case maybe exception.

Comment: @PradeepSimha I had a lucky guess about JNI, but seriously, your comment wasn't wrong, it was just incomplete.  I was just trying to be precise.  Peace, friends.

Answer (score 3):

You can install a 32bit JVM on a 64 bit OS.  Just download it and install it.

No special instructions.  Just the normal tricks with PATH and JAVA_HOME that you use when you have multiple JVMs installed on the same machine ... as described in the installation instructions.

And, yes you can have multiple JVMs installed on the same machine.

Just make sure that you don't install one JVM *on top of* another one.  Install each one in a separate directory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  You can have any number of versions of the JVM on your machine.  You can only point JAVA_HOME to one of them.  When you want to run a program that requires an alternate JVM (e.g. 32-bit) then use a startup script that changes your JAVA_HOME for that execution environment and then runs your program.

I commonly do this for development, especially when supporting many products / versions.

Comment: Interesting, Please guide me more. I want to try it. Plus, is it save ? What risks are involved ?

Comment: Which part do you need guidance on?  Keep your various JDK/JRE installs in versioned folders and switch your JAVA_HOME when you have need.